# How to convert rows returned by a query into columns in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have to display the results of the below query as columns.

```
select to_char(sysdate + 1 - rownum,'MON-YYYY') as d
from all_objects 
where trunc(sysdate + 1 - rownum,'MM') >= trunc(to_date(:from_date,'MON-YYYY'),'MM')
minus
select to_char(sysdate + 1 - rownum,'MON-YYYY') as d
from all_objects 
where trunc(sysdate + 1 - rownum,'MM') > trunc(to_date(':to_date','MON-YYYY'),'MM')
```

Please help me in figuring that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:766825833740